# android Json parsing

Tags: java, android, json

can anyone help,I cant seem to fix the erros while trying to parse this API:

```
{
    "createDate": 1321834118923, 
    "result": "SUCCESS", 
    "searchTerm": "N7", 
    "searchableLocations": [
        {
            "identifier": "OUTCODE^1685", 
            "name": "N7"
        }
    ] 
}
```

Please help me identify the problem

```
   package com.somcollection;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  import org.json.JSONArray;
  import org.json.JSONObject;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;

  public class JsonParser extends Activity {
private JSONObject jObject;


private String jString = "{\"searchTerm\":\"N7\",\"searchableLocations
    \":[{\"identifier\":\"OUTCODE^1685\",\"name\":\"N7\"}],\"createDate
     \":1321834118923,\"result\":\"SUCCESS\"}";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try {
        parse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void parse() throws Exception {
    jObject = new JSONObject(jString);

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jString);    
    String menuObject = jObject.getString("searchTerm");     
    JSONArray menuitemArray = jObject.getJSONArray("searchableLocations");   

    for (int i = 0; i < menuitemArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i);     
        String attributeId = jsonObj.getString("identifier");     
        System.out.println(attributeId);     

        String attributeValue = jsonObj.getString("name");    
        System.out.println(attributeValue); 
    }

    String createDate = jObject.getString("jObject");
    String result = jObject.getString("result");

}
 }
```

Comment: i suggest you use Google's GSON library: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line will fail:

```
String createDate = jObject.getString("jObject");
```

Since you have no key in your JSON named "jObject".  I would expect you would need to write

```
String createDate = jObject.getString("createDate");
```

As a side note, you may not want to use `getString()` for this value either since technically it is defined in the JSON as an integer.

Comment: This is what I have as my original API,I cant answer your question because its above my android knowladge(new to android).  {"searchTerm":"N7","searchableLocations":[{"identifier":"OUTCODE^1685","name":"N7"}],  "createDate":1321834118923,"result":"SUCCESS"} thanks Devunwired,I will add my log soon

Comment: 11-21 22:31:49.030: E/AndroidRuntime(305): 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2585)

11-21 22:31:49.030: E/AndroidRuntime(305):
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

11-21 22:31:49.030: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

11-21 22:31:49.030: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: You should post your logcat as Code in your own post instead of a comment so it doesn't get chopped off :)  However, my statement still stands...unless there is a typo in the code you posted, the line `String createDate = jObject.getString("jObject");` is where your breaking because there is no "jObject" key in your original JSON.

Comment: Devunwired here is my logCat but think is sending the signal now,      11-22 00:06:26.090: I/System.out(490): OUTCODE^1685

11-22 00:06:26.090: I/System.out(490): N7

11-22 00:06:26.100: W/System.err(490): org.json.JSONException: No value for jObject

11-22 00:06:26.100: W/System.err(490):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)

11-22 00:06:26.100: W/System.err(490):  at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)

Comment: 11-22 00:06:26.112: W/System.err(490):  at com.somcollection.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:43)

11-22 00:06:26.112: W/System.err(490):  at com.somcollection.JsonParser.onCreate(JsonParser.java:22)

11-22 00:06:26.120: W/System.err(490):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 11-22 00:06:26.120: W/System.err(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

Comment: 11-22 00:06:26.120: W/System.err(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

11-22 00:06:26.120: W/System.err(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

11-22 00:06:26.120: W/System.err(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

11-22 00:06:26.130: W/System.err(490):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: 11-22 00:06:26.130: W/System.err(490):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

11-22 00:06:26.130: W/System.err(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

11-22 00:06:26.130: W/System.err(490):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

11-22 00:06:26.140: W/System.err(490):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

Comment: 11-22 00:06:26.140: W/System.err(490):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

11-22 00:06:26.170: W/System.err(490):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

11-22 00:06:26.170: W/System.err(490):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Not sure how much clearer I can make this.  Try reading my answer again, that is definitely the problem.

Comment: @Mohamed Next time put that kind of question update into the question rather than comments.

Comment: Devunwired,many thanks for your clear solution.the emulator is recieving a list of pics from the api,just need to display them as listview